# How to display the webcam in HTML page using Python Flask or HTML

Tags: python, html, flask

I have an HTML page. All what I have in this page is a button. When I click this button it will call a python method to start the webcam. It is working perfectly, but the webcam starts in a new prompt. I want to display the webcam prompt in the same HTML page. Is there a way to do that using Flask where I can send the function output to a specific div?
 or using HTML? (I saw few answers but all are using JavaScript)

This is what I have in my HTML page inside `<body>`:

```
<form action="/face/" method="post">
    <button name="face" type="submit">Call my Python Function</button>
</form>
```

and this is what I have in my Flask server:

```
@app.route('/')
def mainPage():
    return render_template('main.html')


@app.route("/face/", methods=['POST'])
def startCam():
    # Start the webcam function
```

Comment: You will probably want to use JavaScript for this instead of python.

Comment: @MustacheMoses Thanks. But I am doing some stuff with my python function that are not supported by Javascript. So can I use Javascript just to display the webcam in the page but still using my Python function?